# Average if in Python with 2 time series

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I want to average the mean value like the average if function in python.

For example let's say I have a set of ranks for A,B,C,D as 'df'
like this picture: 
[image: rank]

and I want the average of the dollar amounts according to the 'ranks':
[image: values to average]

For example, I want the average dollar amount of top two ranks (1 and 2)

I've tried to get boolean dataframes first

```
top = ranks < 3
bot = ranks >=3
```

and tried to loop through it but i don't know if this is the correct way to approach this. thanks alot for your help!

Comment: are you using pandas?

Comment: yes I am using pandas

Comment: Do not using picture here

Comment: sorry for using pictures, im new to the platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ranks = pandas.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [1,3,2,4]], columns=['A','B', 'C', 'D'], index=['2000-01-31', '2000-02-01'])
amounts = pandas.DataFrame([[1,4,1,1], [1,1,1,1]], columns=['A','B', 'C', 'D'], index=['2000-01-31', '2000-02-01'])

top = amounts[ranks<3].mean(axis=1)
bot = amounts[ranks>=3].mean(axis=1)
amounts['top mean'] = top
amounts['bot mean'] = bot
```

ranks

```
            A  B  C  D
2000-01-31  1  2  3  4
2000-02-01  1  3  2  4
```

amounts

```
            A  B  C  D  top mean  bot mean
2000-01-31  1  4  1  1       2.5       1.0
2000-02-01  1  1  1  1       1.0       1.0
```

Comment: thanks! I already have dataframes read in to python from excel files but the logic of your code helped me alot!

Comment: what do you do if the axis is different?

Comment: columns are different? if so, you can reorder either ranks or amounts' columns like `ranks[amounts.columns]`